# loading glNormalPointers and using shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vbo

I'm trying to use my shader to draw along with VAO to do lighting. However whenever I load the glNormalPointer, my shader does not draw on the object and  I am having trouble debugging.

here is part of my code:

```
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
        glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 400, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

It draws correctly but does not do the lighting correctly. If I comment out the three lines that is used to work with normal, then the program would run correctly, which doesn't make sense to me. The normals are just the normals of the face of the surface. They should be correct since when I load them using glNormal3f() along with glVertex3f(), the object renders as below. The shader files are from the lighthouse3d website,  and they have been rendering correctly.

This is with the glNormalPointer() disabled.

[image]

This is with the glNormalPointer enabled, as in not commented out.

[image]

Is there something I missed?

here are the shader codes:
This is the vertext shader i got from lighthouse3d

```
varying vec4 diffuse,ambientGlobal,ambient;
varying vec3 normal,lightDir,halfVector;
varying float dist;

void main()
{   
vec4 ecPos;
vec3 aux;

/* first transform the normal into eye space and normalize the result */
normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

/* now normalize the light's direction. Note that according to the
OpenGL specification, the light is stored in eye space. Also since 
we're talking about a directional light, the position field is actually 
direction */
ecPos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
aux = vec3(gl_LightSource[2].position-ecPos);
lightDir = normalize(aux);

/* compute the distance to the light source to a varying variable*/
dist = length(aux);

/* Normalize the halfVector to pass it to the fragment shader */
halfVector = normalize(gl_LightSource[2].halfVector.xyz);

/* Compute the diffuse, ambient and globalAmbient terms */
diffuse = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * gl_LightSource[2].diffuse;
ambient = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[2].ambient;
ambientGlobal = gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;

gl_Position = ftransform();
 }
```

This is fragment shader i got from lighthouse3d:

```
varying vec4 diffuse,ambientGlobal, ambient;
varying vec3 normal,lightDir,halfVector;
varying float dist;


void main()
{
vec3 n,halfV,viewV,ldir;
float NdotL,NdotHV;
vec4 color = ambientGlobal;
float att;

/* a fragment shader can't write a verying variable, hence we need
a new variable to store the normalized interpolated normal */
n = normalize(normal);

/* compute the dot product between normal and ldir */
NdotL = max(dot(n,normalize(lightDir)),0.0);

if (NdotL > 0.0) {

    att = 1.0 / (gl_LightSource[2].constantAttenuation +
            gl_LightSource[2].linearAttenuation * dist +
            gl_LightSource[2].quadraticAttenuation * dist * dist);
    color += att * (diffuse * NdotL + ambient);


    halfV = normalize(halfVector);
    NdotHV = max(dot(n,halfV),0.0);
    color += att * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * gl_LightSource[2].specular * pow(NdotHV,gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
}

gl_FragColor = color;
```

}

I didn't write any of that, just trying to make them work with my code.

Comment: the result should look like the one in red, but that was through using glVertex3f() and for looping. I'm trying to clean up the code by using glDrawElements and such.

Comment: That's a little better, though I think you should probably show what the value of `normals` is, as well as the source code to your shaders.

Comment: are you asking for all the values of the normal, for each vertex?